# How to retrieved data from mysql using php and show it on javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am trying to create a real time update using php and javascript. For example, If the user added a new client, the number of rows should be reflect on the element of the HTML using javascript. Can someone teach me how to do that? I have this code below, and trying to retrieved it, but it does not have a value.

PHP:

```
<?php
    include("pConfig.php");
    session_start();
    $cntPending = 0;
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM ci_account_info Where Status = 0";
    $result = mysqli_query($db,$sql);
    if (!$result) {
        printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($db));
        exit();
    }
    $cntPending = mysqli_num_rows($result);
?>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
function getTimeSheetValue() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '../back_php_Code/pCntPending.php',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: '',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            success: function (response) {
                                var cells = eval("(" + response.d + ")");
            document.getElementById("lblPending").innerHTML = cell[0].value;
            },
       });    
}
```

HTML:

```
<h4 id="lblPending" class="m-b-0">0</h4>
```

Thank you and Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add echo line in PHP when query is success, then php could send message back to ajax, so change your PHP code:

```
 <?php
     include("pConfig.php");
     session_start();
     $cntPending = 0;
     $sql = "SELECT * FROM ci_account_info Where Status = 0";
     $result = mysqli_query($db,$sql);
     if (!$result) 
     {
         printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($db));
         exit();
     }
     else
     {
         $cntPending = mysqli_num_rows($result);
         echo $cntPending;
     }
 ?>
```

And your javascript need to change a little bit：

```
function getTimeSheetValue(user, pass) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '../back_php_Code/pCntPending.php',
        dataType: 'text',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: function (response) {
                            var cell = response;
        document.getElementById("lblPending").innerHTML = cell;
        },
   });    
}
```